# Upload Data in IntentService when no Internet Connection

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, intentservice

I'v built an IntentService to Upload some Data to Service. But when there's no Internet Connection it doesn't work. How can I wait in my IntentService for Internet Connection? I've found a lot answers with Broadcast Receiver but how can I save the data I want to Upload? If I start a BroadcastReceiver and then start a IntentService, the data I want to Upload is lost.

Does anybody have any Code Example?

Comment: how much data do you have and of what kind,which you want to upload

Comment: If you don't want your data to be lost, you should always put them in database. You can set a `status` column that indicates that you have already uploaded the data or not. every time you try to upload, you should have a look on this table to check whether or not there is some unsuccessful upload.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's not so much data, only some Json String. I will try it with the database. Thanks!